# Replace a text block with sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

This is a snippet from a file:

```
COMMAND : /* some text 1 */
ACTION : /* some text 1 in multiple lines */
COMMAND : /* some text 2 */
ACTION : /* some text 2 in multiple lines */
.
.
.
```

This goes on.
I would like to replace text starting from a COMMAND till its corresponding ACTION (i.e. before the next COMMAND) with another text using sed or awk tool.

So if I want to delete the first COMMAND-ACTION group with some text, the following will be the result.

```
USED SED/AWK HERE
COMMAND : /* some text 2 */
ACTION : /* some text 2 in multiple lines */
.
.
.
```

Comment: How do we know which COMMAND you mean if there are lots?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The text after each COMMAND is different so that might be useful right?

Comment: are there blank line between lines?

Comment: @طاهر Sorry I've edited the snippet. There are no blank lines.

Comment: Since both your `COMMAND-ACTION` group are equal, should they both be replaced?  Do text start with `/*` and end with `*/`?

Comment: @Jotne Yes I need to replace a complete COMMAND-ACTION group with say just a line. /* and */ are not used. I used them just for representational purposes.

Comment: So you like to replace first group, or second group or both group?

Comment: @Jotne I've edited the question. Hope this will help. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: wich are the criteria for selecting the wanted group (you mention 1st, so i could assume another one could be selected or based on COMMAND following text content or maybe something else ...)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu It's the COMMAND following text content.

Comment: What does `It's the COMMAND following text content.` mean? What exactly is `text context` in your posted sample input (`...snippet from a file`)? Are you saying you want to specify some text and then replace the COMMAND/ACTION pair that appears after that text in the input file?

Answer (score 2):

generic to all comand/action

```
sed '/COMMAND/,/ACTION/ {
   /COMMAND/ i\
Put your new text \
and lines here
   d
   }' YourFile
```

specific top your Command text content

```
SearchText='your pattern search text (reduce regex format)"

sed "/COMMAND.*${SearchText}/,/ACTION/ {
   /COMMAND/ i\
Put your new text \
and lines here
   d
   }" YourFile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` like this, and you put your replacement text in a file called `repl.txt`:

```
awk '/^COMMAND x/{del=1;print;system("cat repl.txt");next} {if(!del)print} /^ACTION/{del=0}' file
```

Basically, when it finds the `COMMAND` you  are looking for, it sets the `del` cariable so it knows to delete the action, and it prints the `COMMAND` and includes the text from the file `repo.txt`. It then deletes any lines it sees, until it sees a line starting with `ACTION` when it stops deleting.

`COMMAND x` is the specific COMMAND you are looking for.

Or you can put your replacement text in the awk directly if it is small:

```
awk '/^COMMAND x/{del=1;print;print "Replacement text";next} {if(!del)print} /^ACTION/{del=0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Upvoted:

```
sed '/COMMAND/,/ACTION/ {
/COMMAND/ i\
Put your new text \
and lines here
d
}' YourFile
```

With awk (nawk or gawk really, awk is useless) you can do:

```
replace='myReplaceBlockLine1\nmyReplaceBlockLine2'
nawk '/COMMAND/,/ACTION/{ myvar=replace; gsub(/\\n/,"\n",myvar); print myvar; next} 1'
 "replace=$replace" input_file.txt
```

Downside with both - no backreference support.
Upside with awk - you can add some logic, like replacing only first occurence or removing duplicates

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\nACTION/ ACTION/g' | sed 's/ACTION.*$/MY_TEXT/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This `GNU awk` (due to RS) should skip first group

```
awk -v RS="COMMAND :" 'NR>2 {print RS$0}' file
COMMAND : /* some text 2 */
ACTION : /* some text 2 in multiple lines */
```

Or is it this you mean:

```
awk -v RS="COMMAND :" 'NR>1{$0=RS $0} NR==2 {$0="New text"}1' file

New text
COMMAND : /* some text 2 */
ACTION : /* some text 2 in multiple lines */
```